# How to dynamically add bucket_key value in airflow's S3KeySensor

Tags: python, sensors, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to set S3KeySensor's bucket_key up based on dagrun input variable. 
I have one dag "dag_trigger" that uses TriggerDagRunOperator to trigger dagrun for dag "dag_triggered". I'm trying to extend example https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py.

So I want to send a variable to triggered dag, and according to the variable's value I want to set backet_key value in S3KeySensor task. I know how to use sent variable in PythonOperator callable function, but I do not know how to use it on the sensor object.

dag_trigger dag:

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime.now()}

dag = DAG('dag_trigger', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@hourly")

def task_1_run(context, dag_run_object):
    sent_variable = '2018_02_19' # not important
    dag_run_object.payload = {'message': sent_variable}
    print "DAG dag_trigger triggered with payload: %s" % dag_run_object.payload)
    return dag_run_object

task_1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="task_1",
                               trigger_dag_id="dag_triggered",
                               provide_context=True,
                               python_callable=task_1_run,
                               dag=dag)
```

And dag_triggered dag:

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import S3KeySensor


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime.now()
}

dag = DAG('dag_triggered', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

wait_files_to_arrive_task = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='wait_file_to_arrive',
    bucket_key='file_%s' % '', # Here I want to place conf['sent_variable']
    wildcard_match=True,
    bucket_name='test-bucket',
    s3_conn_id='test_s3_conn',
    timeout=18*60*60,
    poke_interval=120,
    dag=dag)
```

I tried to get the value from dag object using dag.get_dagrun().conf['sent_variable'] but I have a doubt how to set dagrun create_date variable (dag_trigger will triggered dag_triggered every hour and dag_triggered could wait longer for file).

I also tried to create PythonOperator that would be upstream for wait_files_to_arrive_task. The callable python function could get information about sent_variable. After that I tried to set value for bucket_key like bucket_key = callable_function() - but I have problem with arguments.

And I also think the global variables is not good solution.

Maybe someone has idea that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to fetch a value in your DAG run conf directly in your DAG file. That's something that cannot be determined without context of which DAG run it's part of. One way to think about it is when you run `python my_dag.py` to test if your DAG file compiles, it has to initialize all these operators without needing to specify an execution date. So anything that could differ by DAG run can't be referenced directly.

So instead, you can pass it as a template value which will later get rendered with context when the task is actually being run.

```
wait_files_to_arrive_task = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='wait_file_to_arrive',
    bucket_key='file_{{ dag_run.conf["message"] }}',
    ...)
```

Note that only parameters listed in the `template_fields` of an operator will be rendered. Luckily someone anticipated this so [bucket_key](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/operators/sensors.py#L507) is indeed a template field.

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much. This is wonderful. Actually I tried template and obviously I have invalid syntax ('file_' % '{{dag_run.conf[''message'']}}' or 'file_' % `{{dag_run.conf['message']}}`). I need to learn to use templates.